# Cannot connect to Windows 10 over SSH running OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, windows-10, openssh

I have a Windows 10 machine running OpenSSH that I need to connect to over SSH using PuTTY. I have created a public/private key on the Host machine using PuTTYgen. I loaded the public into the user's profile directory under .ssh/authorized_keys. When I connect with PuTTY from a machine outside the network I get this error message:

```
"Server refused our key"
```

I have read several posts and they all indicate the public key is not being read correctly. I have made the following changes with no success.

1. Update user permissions on .ssh and /authorized_keys setting the User as the owner.
2. Currently my .ssh folder is located in %SYSTEMDRIVE%/users/[USERNAME]/.ssh
3. I recreated this directory on my data drive to be sure that was not an issue: "D:/users/[USERNAME]/.ssh
4. Because the account I am using is an administrator account I have created "%Program Data/ssh/adminstrators_authorized_keys
5. I commented out the line in sshd_config that looks at the file in #4 when the user is an administrator.

None of these attempts have cleared up the problem. I have never set up SSH on a Windows 10 host before so I am out of ideas. I set up logging in sshd_config but there are no log files being generated.

Can someone help me get this figured out?

Comment: Does the remote machine have port 22 open? Does the remote network have port 22 forwarded?

Comment: Yes port 22 is open in firewall and accepts the connection. I can telnet over 22 with no problem and I can see successful entries in the firewall logs.

Comment: Another test I have done to be sure 22 is working is I can log in through the SSH connection if I enter the password for my user account. So I can confirm that port 22 is working and that SSH is accepting a connection, I just can't get the public/private keys to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as in [this tutorial](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/#copy-public-key-to-server), make sure to copy an OpenSSH public key

> The OpenSSH public key is located in the box under `Key / Public key for pasting info OpenSSH authorized_keys file`:. The public key begins with `ssh-rsa` followed by a string of characters.

Second, as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edcote/abf0d4261fc2b35fe18aa5bd5ecfd849), launch `sshd -d` to get a one time session in debug mode: you will see more clues as to why it rejects your public key.

---

The [OP gacto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4733091/gacto) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365074/cannot-connect-to-windows-10-over-ssh-running-openssh/63370735#comment112278348_63370735):

> `sshd -d` gave me the information I needed.
>
> It was a file permissions issue. I had set the file permissions to the specifications from the OpenSSH setup instructions, but access to the file was getting blocked.
> Once I updated the file permissions, I was able to connect without any trouble.

Comment: sshd -d gave me the information I needed. it was a file permissions issue. i had set the file permissions to the specifications from the OpenSSH setup instructions, but access to the file was getting blocked. once i updated the file permissions i can connect without any trouble. thanks for the help.

Comment: @gacto Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the message in `sshd -d` was

> Failed publickey for [user] from [IP] port [port] ssh2: RSA SHA256:[fingerprint]

The cause was that the `authorized_keys` file was in UTF-16 format. It needs to be UTF-8 to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your user in Windows10 is active.
By default for instance the user Administrator is not active, and should be enabled with:

```
net user Administrator /active:yes
```